# Sub panel install, conduit run behind natural gas line?

Tags: electrical, conduit, natural-gas

Looks for rules on whether I can run a 1" electrical conduit along bottom of house if it crosses the natural gas line? They do not touch and there would be about 3" between the 2 above ground. If yes, does it matter if EMT or schedule 40 PVC conduit? Running a sub panel to garage.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: If PVC you need schedule 80 as it's "exposed to damage" at that level.

Comment: Okay thanks not a problem. Any feedback on whether it can run behind the natural gas line?

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of rules ("building codes") about how conduit is done and how gas piping is done, but to my knowledge there aren't any that address required separation between gas and electricity.

A code-compliant installation will minimize the risk of causing a hazard (risk of leaking gas, risk of arcing or bare conductors, etc) and will provide reasonable protection against external factors that could damage the installation (gas pipe and electrical conduit will have enough physical strength to resist damage if accidentally struck, etc).